# option to disable downloading from jupterlab and notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I am running jupyterlab with jupyterhub (on AWS with K8S) and using sensitive data, so i want to disable the option to download and export files from the lab to local machines.

The only way i could think of doing this was to edit the jupyter lab & jupyter notebook src code, remove the option and the functions that download files, and install these on my pods instead of the default jupyter lab & notebook
BUT this does not stop the user from going directly to the url and download the file from there.

Has anyone done something like this ? I saw in the jupyterlab forum in Github that there are a few issues open on the subject, but nothing is resolved

Answer (score 5):

They have reached [v3.1.0(prerelease)](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/releases/tag/v3.1.0a8) Now, the download option can be disabled as an extension using `jupyter labextension disable @jupyterlab/docmanager-extension:download`.

Also for the download option in right-click menu, can be disabled using `jupyter labextension disable @jupyterlab/filebrowser-extension:download`.

More info can be found at [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5274)